# function reference instead of function body - in a loop (with argument)

Tags: javascript

I would like to replace this:

```
for( var i=0; i<elementArray.length; i++ )
   elementArray[i].click(function(){
      console.log("element clicked - selectedElementIndex = " + i);                    
   });
```

with something like:

```
for( var i=0; i<elementArray.length; i++ )
    elementArray[i].click( onElementClick(i) );

function onElementClick( i ){
   console.log("element clicked - selectedElementIndex = " + i ); 
}
```

how can I do it ? :)

Comment: What does the entire for loop look like. Please post it as an edit without the `...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since (as far as I know) the click handler can't take arguments, you need to make a function with the variable in scope, which should look something like this:

```
for( ... ) {
    elementArray[i].click( onElementClick(i) );
    ...
}

function onElementClick( id ){
   return function() {
       console.log("element clicked - selectedElementIndex = " + id ); 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
elementArray[i].click( onElementClick(i) );
```

With:

```
elementArray[i].click( onElementClick(elementArray[i].id));
```

Comment: @eicto, obviously someone thinks so if he downvoted, I'm asking why it's incorrect...

Comment: What is `elementArray[i].id` when he's just using `id`? Is that just psuedocode or something?

Comment: Hi gdoron, I am actually not storing an id inside the elementArray, is there any way of doing it without it? It is not a major problem to store the id, but just wondering if there was a solution without wtoring extra info just for this

Comment: @san.chez, you really didn't not show us enough of your code and what you want to achieve. :(

Comment: I think better is really story id in element data

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a function expression:

```
elementArray[i].click(function() {

    onElementClick(i);

});
```

You also need to wrap the code in a function expression as well to avoid sticky problems:

```
(function() {

    ...

    for ( ... ) (function(i) {

        elementArray[i].click(function() {

            onElementClick(i);

        });

    })(i);

})();
```

Comment: @san.chez, warning `i` will give you the last value of the for loop. unless you use closure. I'm too tired to explain... good night. **Update: Jeff answer seems to be just what you want, I upvoted it.**

Comment: David, you didn't use closure at all.

Comment: @gdoron Meant function expression.

Comment: @David. The problem remained, you use the loop variable where it's not safe. I'm really need going to sleep, when can "talk" about it later. Good Night.

Comment: @David the problem here is that the `i` variable is not captured in the function expression. Because of this, the `i` inside the function is updated at the same time as the `i` outside the function. This means that if the loop is run ten times, and then an item is clicked, the resulting value will always be `9` (assuming the loop runs 0-9). This is because that's the last value that the `i` variable had during that closure.

Comment: @Jeff I realize this, that's why I asked to see the entire for loop so I can make an edit with the revised code...

Comment: @san.chez please see my edit. Wrap the body of the for loop in a closure.

Comment: Assuming that `i` comes from the for loop, the edit won't make any difference - it just adds a new closure that will still update `i` inside the click callback... you need to capture each value of `i` inside a separate closure in order to avoid the problem. In fact, even if `i` comes from outside the top anonymous function it'll still do that... though you could fix that by passing `i` as an argument to the top anonymous function, thus capturing it within the closure.

Answer (score 0):

Using `data` it could be look like:

```
for (... {

  elementArray[i].click( onElementClick ).data('id',i);
}

function onElementClick(){
       console.log("element clicked - selectedElementIndex = " + $(this).data('id') ); 
}
```